# SQL Server : Conditional where clause (Equal) OR (LessThan or Equal)

Tags: sql-server, variables, conditional-statements, where-clause

```
WHERE [Date] <= CASE    
                   WHEN @param = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
                   WHEN @param = 2 THEN DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE())
```

The example above passes in variable `@param` which is intended to filter for:

- `@param = 1` *(All days less than or inclduing today)*.
- `@param = 2` *(All days less than or inclduing today and tomorrow)*.
- `@param = 3` *(Today only)*. This requires a change to the expression.

**QUESTION**

In SQL Server, how do you create a conditional `where` clause that evaluates different equality?

```
WHERE [Date] <= 
WHERE [Date] =
```

OR put another way:

How can I add a filter for just today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
where 
    ([date] <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) and @param = 1) or
    ([date] <= DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE()) and @param = 2) or
    ([date] = GETDATE() and @param = 3)
```

Comment: Beautiful and elegant solution. Nice work. **Note**: I had to bracket each side of every `and` statement to make it valid.